# Bootstrap 3 - Dropdown menu item on hover doesnt display content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My dropdown menu (that one with map img) doesnt work, it should display content from class named dropdown. Thank You very much for help.

[image: Problem menu item]

```
<header class="navbar-fixed-top">
<div id="menu-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <h2 class="head-text">ATS GLOBAL - {$txt_head1}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="" data-hover="dropdown"><img src="/images/images/mapimg.png" alt="" /> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">programowanie</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">grafika</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">wideo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DTP</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
        </div>           
    </div>    
</div>
.....
```

Comment: Army of debuggers. Let's go.

Comment: @blex Hi, no I've included jquery 2.0.3, bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.js. Which plugin should I use ? Thx

Comment: @blex I included plugin that you post me, clear browser cache and same effect as before.

Comment: OK, then I'm going to delete my comments and let someone else answer.

Comment: @blex I've tried data-toggle="dropdown" and after i click on that map it displays nothing.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
.dropdown {
  background: url( "/images/images/mapimg.png") no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 100px; //Your image's height
}
```

Comment: xD Thank you for this post. Made my day.